# Display pdf file using chromecast

Tags: ios, chromecast

I'm new to both iOS developing and chromecast. I'm writing an app on iOS so that I can display a pdf file stored on my iOS device to a bigger screen using chromecast. Is this doable?

Comment: for starters, http://pspdfkit.com/ is the way to go for loading PSDs on iOS

Comment: Looks like a very cool tool. But is there a way for chromecast to "stream" the pdf files? Or tell chromecast to share a specific part of the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chromecast renders HTML, so if you can render your PDF document in HTML, then that is doable, otherwise, I am afraid not.

Comment: Is there a way to do partial screen sharing using chromecast?

Comment: I presume you mean screen mirroring? If so, neither full nor partial mirroring is supported on Android, nor on iOS.

Comment: Sorry but could you elaborate on how to render the pdf file in html? Also, is it possible to convert a pdf page to a jpeg/png/gif file and cast it?

Comment: These are the questions you need to answer and figure out for yourself (basically that is what your app will be about, right?) they are not cast related at all and if you need help, you might want to post something under a different tag so people familiar with the internals of PDF can help you.